# Elasticsearch failed to start on macos

Tags: elasticsearch, homebrew

I've installed Elasticsearch using brew on macos Monterey

```
brew install elasticsearch
```

But I can't start the service

```
brew services start elasticsearch
```

[image]

```
brew info elasticsearch
```

[image]

This are the log

```
warning: no-jdk distributions that do not bundle a JDK are deprecated and will be removed in a future release
warning: no-jdk distributions that do not bundle a JDK are deprecated and will be removed in a future release
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
at java.base/java.lang.System.setSecurityManager(System.java:416)
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:82)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run:

```
brew info elasticsearch
```

You will see:

> Deprecated because it is switching to an incompatible license. Check out `opensearch` instead!

So you should either use [opensearch](https://opensearch.org/), which is:

> a community-driven, open source search and analytics suite derived from Apache 2.0 licensed Elasticsearch 7.10.2 & Kibana 7.10.2.

or if you want to stay with Elasticsearch use the [official installation method for macOS](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.1/targz.html) which consists of using a tar.gz:

```
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-8.1.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-8.1.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz.sha512
shasum -a 512 -c elasticsearch-8.1.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz.sha512 
tar -xzf elasticsearch-8.1.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
cd elasticsearch-8.1.2/
```

alternatively you can use an official [Docker image](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.1/docker.html).

Comment: I solved with opensearch, thanks!

Comment: Opensearch 2.0 has been released and seems to now suffer from the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Just adding something which might be useful for someone.
If you're running elastic on a Mac M1 architecture, depending on how you run elastic, you might need to setup this property:

```
  xpack.ml.enabled=- false
```

Comment: where to setup this property

Answer (score -2):

**For Mac Users**

> System Settings > Privacy & Security > Developer Tools

Check/Add the terminal and start the elastic search from the terminal.